# Unix commands in a windows server container - Docker Windows

Tags: windows, docker, unix, cygwin, containers

Can I **run unix commands in a windows server container** docker for windows?

I tried Cygwin tools installed in my host (Windows) in the docker but that doesn't work.
*--Perhaps the cygwin binaries are built in another OS than Windows10 ?*

Have you some tips for me ? Thanks.

Comment: Is Cygwin not opening or the command you provide is not executing? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The commads (Sed, grep, ls ...) doesn't run, but "sleep" for example run. When I try to execute "sed" for example or another command I haven't any error message,

Comment: Commands installed on the host are not going to help you inside the container. You should consider using the "equivalent" PowerShell commands in your windows container.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding cygwin's bin folder to your PATH or use full path when running cygwin's commands. i.e: `C:\cygwin64\bin\ls.exe c:\some\dir`.
sleep is also a windows command, so it works unrelated to cygwin installation.